# pass quoted string argument in sh script

Tags: shell, quoting

I simply don't understand

**command-line (works):**

```
$ someprog -flag 'key1=val 1,key2=val 2,key3=val 3'
```

**sh direct (works):**

```
#!/bin/sh
someprog -flag 'key1=val 1,key2=val 2,key3=val 3'
```

**sh variable (fails):**

```
#!/bin/sh
OPTSTR="'key1=val 1,key2=val 2,key3=val 3'"
someprog -flag "$OPTSTR"      #fails
someprog -flag ${OPTSTR}      #fails
someprog -flag $OPTSTR        #fails
eval "someprog -flag $OPTSTR" #works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first two examples you quote your argument. Those quotes are only seen by your shell, which treats the whole string as a single argument instead of splitting it on the spaces. The quotes itself are not seen by the program.

When typing `OPTSTR="'key1=val 1,key2=val 2,key3=val 3'"` the content of your variable contains the single quotes, and will therefore later be given to your program. Your program sees the quotes, does not expect them and therefore fails.

Simply use:

```
OPTSTR="key1=val 1,key2=val 2,key3=val 3"
someprog -flag "$OPTSTR"
```

The difference between single and double quotes is, whether you want your shell to replace variables and such or not.

Comment: from the first 2 examples, the program *does* expect a singly-quoted string as an argument

Comment: no it does not. ;) those quotes are handled by your shell. the actual program does never see those quotes.

Comment: wait, are we talking about the command-line and sh direct examples?

Comment: about both. in both cases your shell is evaluating the line. (in the one case you have an interactive shell, in the other case it is used non-interactive.)

Comment: ah you are indeed right! all these quotes are confusing me :/ Thanks for your patience and your help!